# Topological order question and load path question (Python)

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm having problems with problems 3 and 4 located on the following folder: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19iYoPrKKU_4MXenPpC1bBI8dmrzsxaWa/view?usp=sharing
Inside the folder, there are multiple python files and also a word file called homework 2 that explains all the questions and the objectives. The working file is called "network.py" and contains all the problems. There is a file called "grader.py" if you run the file it will tell you your score on all 4 questions. I have done the first two questions and now I'm stuck with question 3 and have no idea how to do question 4. So far I have the following code for question 3:

```
for i in self.node:
    self.node[i].order = []
node_list= list()
    for i in self.node:
        if len(self.node[i].reverseStar) == 0:
            node_list.append(i)
            break
if len(node_list)== 0:
    raise BadNetworkOperationException()
while (len(node_list)!=self.numNodes):
    for i in [x for x in self.node if x not in node_list]:
        incoming_nodes = [int(j[1]) for j in self.node[i].reverseStar if j not in node_list]
        if (len(incoming_nodes)== 0):
            node_list.append(i)
            break
for k in range(len(node_list)):
    self.node[node_list[k]].order = k+1
return self.node[i].order
```

When I try to run the grader the program runs forever. I'm lost now. I appreciate the help anyone can provide.

Comment: please describe the problem you're trying to solve right in your post.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).